# iOS 11 EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS on dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios11, swift4

Can't replicate a crash on iOS 11 devices when deallocating the `DetailViewController`.

The app has a `DetailViewController` which inherits from the `BaseViewController`. `DetailViewController` has a `DetailViewModel` property.

`DetailViewController`, `BaseViewController` and `DetailViewModel` are all written in Objective-C. I upgraded the Swift version to `Swift 4` and added a Swift Extension to `DetailViewModel`.

```
@objc extension DetailViewModel {
        func foo() {
            let conclusionBlock: (() -> Void) = { [weak self] in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                strongSelf.viewController.reloadData()
            }
            let viewModel = OtherViewModel(conclusionBlock: conclusionBlock)
            let otherViewController = OtherViewController.make(viewModel: viewModel)

            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: otherViewController)
            nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

            viewController.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Looking at the logs, `func foo()` in the `DetailViewModel` swift extension is not called and it's still crashing on dealloc.

Has anyone got ideas as to what's the issue or how to fix it?

Thank you

stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18589d7f4 objc_object::release() + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1862f3108 cow_cleanup + 112
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18623a51c -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 68
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18587eef4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c638 objc_destructInstance + 88
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c690 object_dispose + 16
6  AppName                        0x100c7dbec -[DetailViewModel .cxx_destruct] (DetailViewModel.m:43)
7  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18587eef4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c638 objc_destructInstance + 88
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c690 object_dispose + 16
10 AppName                        0x100cbe358 -[DetailViewController .cxx_destruct] (DetailViewController.m:103)
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18587eef4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c638 objc_destructInstance + 88
13 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c690 object_dispose + 16
14 UIKit                          0x18fb338f4 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 156
15 UIKit                          0x18f8e9e7c -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1776
16 AppName                        0x100c9b66c -[BaseViewController dealloc] (BaseViewController.m:56)
17 AppName                        0x100cb6570 -[DetailViewController dealloc] (DetailViewController.m:261)
18 UIKit                          0x18f9d3ec4 __destroy_helper_block_.150 + 80
19 libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x185d91a60 _Block_release + 160
20 UIKit                          0x18fa5f5bc -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate .cxx_destruct] + 72
21 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18587eef4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
22 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c638 objc_destructInstance + 88
23 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18588c690 object_dispose + 16
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18623d998 -[__NSDictionaryI dealloc] + 136
25 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18589e138 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 836
26 CoreFoundation                 0x186232050 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
27 CoreFoundation                 0x186311b04 __CFRunLoopRun + 2020
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1862322d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
29 GraphicsServices               0x1880c3f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
30 UIKit                          0x18f7df880 UIApplicationMain + 208
31 AppName                        0x100d59540 main (main.m:10)
32 libdyld.dylib                  0x185d5656c start + 4
```

Answer (score 2):

To help with replicating the issue, try turning on Address Sanitizer in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 1):

You have an object stored in an array that is over-released when the object is destroyed and is releasing its array.

You can first activate `zombie objects` (clic your target near the PLAY button, choose `scheme/Run/Diagnostics/Zombie objects`). in this mode, objects are not really released, so you can query the object causing the crash to see what is its type and begin to track it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but we tried it with zombie objects enabled and we managed to get someone to make it crash once, but it didn't trigger anything